# transform varchar into workable date field

Tags: apache-superset

I import the data from my database. I have a date field which is of type varchar(10). My date field look like this: dd/mm/yyyy. How can I transform this to workable date field in superset ? I have the version 3.0.0

---

My date text column named periodDate
I go to Dataset > edit my dataset (table 1) > calculated columns

- SQL expression: *Select CAST(periodDate AS DATE) From `table 1`*
- Label: *periodDate_cast*

I create a time-serie line chart

- time column: periodDate_cast
- time grain: Year
- metrics: Sum(value)
- dimension: periodDate_cast

I get an error:

```
Unexpected error
Error: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Select CAST (periodDate AS DATE)\n               From `table 1`, INTERVAL DAYOFYE' at line 2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is to cast your string into a date before the data reaches Superset.
Superset per se doesn't import/store data, so all the operations are done on the database side.

Just add a `CAST (string AS DATE)` on the column you want, you can do this either as a calculated column in an existing dataset or in a query that you then save as a virtual dataset.

Comment: Hello, can I create a  calculated columns ? I see that we can enter an SQL query. I do * Select CAST(periodDate AS DATE) From \`table 1\`* but I get a error i edit my main post.

Comment: I think your SQL expression should be just : `CAST(periodDate AS DATE)`

Just tested this and it works fine in mariaDB: https://onecompiler.com/mariadb/3zsvzjy4d